# Image borders change onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 images in the same div id="palettes", I want all images to have 3px solid grey border, the one clicked change to black.

The code works, but when I click any of this 5 images inside the div the javascript add 3px solid grey to all images in the page not only in the div I want. How do I specify this in the code?

```js
    $('#palettes img').click(function () {
        $('img').not($(this)).css({'border':'3px solid grey'});
        $(this).css({'border':'3px solid black'});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="palettes">
     <a href="javascript:;"><img style="border: 3px solid grey;" src="palette1.jpg"/></a>
     <a href="javascript:;"><img style="border: 3px solid grey;" src="palette2.jpg"/></a>
     <a href="javascript:;"><img style="border: 3px solid grey;" src="palette3.jpg"/></a>
     <a href="javascript:;"><img style="border: 3px solid grey;" src="palette4.jpg"/></a>
     <a href="javascript:;"><img style="border: 3px solid grey;" src="palette5.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: but your code is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Bah, I just fixed it. Sorry.

```
$('#palettes img').click(function () {
    $('#palettes img').not($(this)).css({'border':'3px solid grey'});
    $(this).css({'border':'3px solid black'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `children` element to access to all children of an element:

```
  $('#palettes img').click(function () {
     $( '#palettes' ).children( 'img' ).css( {'border':'3px solid grey'} );
    });

<div id="palettes">
    <a href="javascript:;"><img style="border: 3px solid grey;" src="palette1.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"><img style="border: 3px solid grey;" src="palette2.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"><img style="border: 3px solid grey;" src="palette3.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"><img style="border: 3px solid grey;" src="palette4.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"><img style="border: 3px solid grey;" src="palette5.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```